# How to call WCF service with ADFS issued Security Token

Tags: web-services, wcf, security, wif, adfs

I have an MVC web applicationt that has been confuigured to connect to ADFS to authenticate users and get a security token. The application then needs to call a WCF service using that security token.

The config of the web app is

```
  <system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">

  <claimsAuthenticationManager type="MvcApplication1.Security.ClaimsTransformer, MvcApplication1" />
  <claimsAuthorizationManager type="MvcApplication1.Security.AuthorisationManager, MvcApplication1" />

  <audienceUris>
    <add value="https://edd05rgard.hd.dev/adfsproto/web/" />
  </audienceUris>

  <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <trustedIssuers>
      <add thumbprint="49F27C0DD1044D73011894450727E3C3E55DA428" name="http://EDV05TESTADFS1.hdtest.hd.dev/adfs/services/trust" />
    </trustedIssuers>
  </issuerNameRegistry>

</identityConfiguration>
```

```
<federationConfiguration>
  <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />

  <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true"
                issuer="https://edv05testadfs1.hdtest.hd.dev/adfs/ls/"
                realm="https://edd05rgard.hd.dev/adfsproto/web/"
                reply="https://edd05rgard.hd.dev/adfsproto/web/"
                requireHttps="true" />
</federationConfiguration>
```

This successfully gets the token from ADFS and I can transform claims within the app as expected.

I then try to make a call to a WCF service using the supplied security token:

```
        BootstrapContext bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;

        var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        binding.Security.Message.IssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://edv05testadfs1.hdtest.hd.dev/adfs/ls");

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://edd05rgard.hd.dev/adfsproto/service/ClaimsService.svc");

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IClaimsService>(binding, endpoint);
        factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
        factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;

        var context = (BootstrapContext)((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).BootstrapContext;
        var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(context.SecurityToken, endpoint);

        var result = channel.GetClaimsWithDelegation();
```

When this code is executed the last line causes an exception:

> An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An error occurred when processing the security tokens in the message.

Am I calling the service in the correct way? How can I investigate the errors in the security token?